# Which HTTP version is claimed to be the fastest?

Tags: http, https

Which version do you guys believe is the fastest? 0.9, 1.0, 1.1 or 2.0?

Comment: It seems it is 2.0. This link might help you: https://hpbn.co/http2/

Answer (score 0):

definitely **HTTP/2** and it is latest version

**HTTP/2 Protocol Overview**

---

HTTP/2 provides an optimized transport for HTTP semantics. HTTP/2 supports all of the core features of HTTP/1.1 but aims to be more efficient in several ways.

The basic protocol unit in HTTP/2 is a frame. Each frame type serves a different purpose. For example, HEADERS and DATA frames form the basis of HTTP requests and response; other frame types like `SETTINGS`, `WINDOW_UPDATE`, and `PUSH_PROMISE` are used in support of other HTTP/2 features.

**Multiplexing** of requests is achieved by having each HTTP request/response exchange associated with its own stream. Streams are largely independent of each other, so a blocked or stalled request or response does not prevent progress on other streams.

**Flow control** and **prioritization** ensure that it is possible to efficiently use multiplexed streams. Flow control helps to ensure that only data that can be used by a receiver is transmitted. Prioritization ensures that limited resources can be directed to the most important streams first